# Eliminar coma del último elemento del array php

Tags: php

Tengo una array con unas tallas separadas por coma, lo que necesito hacer es que cuando yo vaya a  eliminar cualquiera de los elementos me borre también la coma, lo que pasa es que como el último elemento no tiene coma al final y yo utilizo `str_replace` con la coma entonces no me está funcionando, acá les muestro el código:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
tallas = $_POST["tallas"];
$array = explode(",", str_replace($id.',', '', $tallas));
```

En la variable `$id` tengo el índice del elemento que voy a eliminar y en la variable `$tallas` tengo el array con las diferentes tallas que mando por `$_POST`.

Comment: Podrias poner el valor que obtienes de `$_POST["tallas"];`?

Comment: Sí claro: '11,28,33,36,37,38'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he resuelto, lo que hice fue verificar si el elemento que voy a eliminar va a ser el último, y si es así entonces elimino la coma anterior y si no es el último elemento entonces elimino la coma siguiente:

```
if($id === end($arr)) {
        $array = explode(",", str_replace(','.$id, '', $tallas));
} else {
        $array = explode(",", str_replace($id.',', '', $tallas));
}
```

Comment: Por lo que veo, lo que recibes en $id no es el índice si no el valor del elemento que quieres eliminar... aún así te sugiero que uses unset después de transformar la entrada a array

Comment: Así me funciona bien, gracias, no sé porque insistes

Comment: si te funciona está ok, simplemente me parece que estás haciendo algo más complicado de lo necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno la idea es la siguiente, aunque al parecer la respuesta que te dieron hace rato funciona bien pero intentaré explicarte con más detalle:

**Primero:** Tienes una variable de tipo *Int* llamada `$id` que segun comentas almacena el índice que quieres eliminar.

**Segundo:** Tienes una segunda variable de tipo *String* llamada `$tallas` que como su nombre indica almacena las tallas pero cada una separadas por una coma (Ej:  '11,28,33,36,37,38').

Hasta ahí vamos bien, ahora lo que puedes hacer como bien te dice @Muc es hacer un [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) por la coma para poder partir cada una de las tallas y así tener un array:

```
$arrTallas = explode(',', $tallas);
```

Con esto tendrás un array así:  [11, 28, 33, 36, 37, 38], que en posiciones corresponde a [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Bien ahora procedamos a utilizar [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) para eliminar el elemento del array en este caso como ejemplo diremos que `$id = 3`.

Entonces en código veríamos algo así:

```
unset($arrTallas[$id]);
```

Que en teoría y bajo el valor que le dimos para el ejemplo vendría a ser `unset($arrTallas[3]);`. Al hacer esto la variable `$arrTallas` debería haber quedado así: [11, 28, 33, 37, 38]. Sin el valor 36 que fué el que eliminamos.

Ahora si quieres volver a convertir tu variable array a un string simplemente haremos uso de la función [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode) que volverá a unir tu array de la siguiente forma:

```
$tallas = implode(',', $arrTallas);
```

Quedando todo tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
tallas = $_POST["tallas"];
$arrTallas = explode(',', $tallas);
unset($arrTallas[$id]);
$tallas = implode(',', $arrTallas);
```

Cualquier duda o problema que tengas, o si no entendí bien alguna parte de tu problema explícamela en los comentarios.

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Te conviene convertir el array usando explode y después hacer unset:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$tallas = explode(",", $_POST["tallas"]);
unset($tallas[$id]);
```

Comment: acabo de intentarlo pero no me funciona, sigue mostrando las mismas tallas

Comment: Esto deberia funcionar si el `id` te devuelve la posicion del array. Por ejemplo tu resultado de `$_POST["tallas"]` es `'11,28,33,36,37,38'`, entonces si quieres eliminar el `11`, el valor de `$_POST["id"]` tiene que ser `0` @NoéMuñoz